# Heroku require_once error

Tags: php, heroku

I am developing a php application locally, and all works well until I push to heroku, where the log gives me this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/app/src/web/../../etc/s_init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/src/web/index.php on line 2
```

This is the troublesome piece of code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../etc/s_init.php');
```

It works locally but doesn't work when pushed to heroku.  The directory looks like this:

```
- etc
   - s_init.php
- src
   - web
      - index.php
```

I have run out of ideas at this point.  Why is this error occurring, and how can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem:

> (/app/src/web/../../etc/s_init.php)

That's not a valid path.
Try this:

```
require_once('../../etc/s_init.php');
```

Comment: I tried that previously, and it gave the same error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../etc/s_init.php'

Comment: I read that from this website: https://discussion.heroku.com/t/adding-vendor-directory-to-heroku-application/697

Comment: what if you use an absolute path from root using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?